# Python Interpreting things from document

Tags: python-2.5

So, I am essentially just dreaming up ideas right now.

I was wondering if it was possible to make a python program that can read a document, take a line from the document, make an if/else statement with it (Like if the text on that line is equal to Hello, than say hello back), and then continue onto the next line. I have already kind of done this in a shell fashion but I want to see if it is possible to have python read the line of a document, interpret it, display something, and move on to the next line of the document.

(I am prepared for this post to get tons of -1's for not knowing how to program a lot of python, and probably just not being clear enough. So before you -1, just add a comment saying what you need me to be clear about.)

The version of python of my choice would be 2.5.

Comment: do you mean by "document" just a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know any Python, try this:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == "Hello":
            print "Hello back"
```

or without the exception-safe clause:

```
    for line in open("file.txt"):
        if line.strip() == "Hello":
            print "Hello back"
```

the `strip()` removes the ending newline `\n` from the line

Comment: Thank you as well! This was also helpful. Sadly, I haven't gained enough medals yet to upvote.

Comment: Is there a way to do this so it will continuously go to the next line while reading the same if and else statements already defined?

Comment: What? Please learn some basics before asking such questions. What you see in my code is a loop, so the `if` applies to every line

Comment: Never mind! Sorry, I just never looked at your second example. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One last question, In your second exception-safe clause, you show it opening and reading a line from a file and making an if and else statement with it which is what I asked. Can you show me how to assign variables to lines in the document within the if statement? (I tried file.readline and it gives me an error)

Answer (score -1):

That is actually a very simple task in Python:

```
file = open("file.txt")  # open the file

while True:
    word = file.readline()  # read a line from the file
    print word  # print it to the console
    if word == "":  # if out of words...
        file.close()   # ...close the file
        break   # and break from while loop and exit program
```

Comment: Will try this... Thank you so much for solving this!

Comment: While technically correct, this is not only unpythonic, but just bad code.

Comment: Mostly unpythonic. First, using a `while True` loop combined with `break` can be considered bad manner. Try to structure your loops with clear conditions. Python is good at this. Second, Manually closing a filehandle should be avoided by using the modern, exception-safe `with`. Third, python's file object is designed to be line-iterable with a for-loop. There is no need to manually read lines and check for EOL. Fourth, your code prints double newlines; the ones from the file and the ones that the print-statement appends.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. To be honest, I personally prefer `while True` loops combined with `break`; and as for the use of `with` with files and pythons build-in for-loop functionality with files, I was unaware that was even a thing. And I did notice it printed double newlines, just didn't really bother to fix it :P Thank you though, I learnt two new things today :)